issue with mutate and if's in R 4.4.0
I updated R to it's new version 4.4.0 and I'm finding errors which I didn't had
for example, this used to work:
temp <- data.frame("a"=c(1,2),"b"=c(3,4),"c"=0)

temp <- temp %>% mutate(c=if(a>b){100}else{200})

the c column would update to 200 in every line. but now I got this error

So, what's the new correct way to do an update with a condition?

Did you run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred?

Change to ifelse(); this works: data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4)) |> dplyr::mutate(c = ifelse(a > b, 100L, 200L))

if always needed and needs one value at a time (it's not vectorized), hence the error message.
Either do
library(dplyr)

temp %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(c = if(a > b){100}else{200})

or
temp %>% 
  mutate(c = if_else(a > b, 100, 200))

