`dplyr::mutate` with Logical Expressions Involving Factors
I am trying to mutate a new column in an R tibble which is a logical equation of existing factor columns. I keep encountering the error the condition has length > 1  despite the simple control flow of my problem. My actual code has a more complex logical flow and works fine on some factor columns but not others.
Here is an MRE:
my_tibble <- tibble::tibble(a = as.factor(c("dog","cat","dog")), b = as.factor(c(1,5,6)))
my_fn <- function(a, b){
    if (a == "dog"){
        if (b == 1){
            return(12)
        } else{
            return(3)
        }
    } else{
        return(5)
    }
}
dplyr::mutate(my_tibble, c = my_fn(a,b)) # Error here!

However, my_tibble[1,1] == "dog" evaluates to TRUE.
The error itself is:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `c = my_fn(a, b)`.
Caused by error in `if (a == "dog") ...`:
! the condition has length > 1

I have to imagine there is something about logical expressions involving factors I am missing here. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Factors are not the issue. The issue is your if(). If you look at the help page, it tells you: "A length-one logical vector that is not NA.". Your "a" is not length 1.

Adding to Edward: Use ifelse or dplyr::case_when, e.g. case_when(a == "dog" & b == 1 ~ 12, a == "dog" ~ 3, .default = 5). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433704/difference-between-if-and-ifelse-functions for the difference between if and ifelse.

This exact issue was answered earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78557063/issue-with-mutate-and-ifs-in-r-4-4-0

Thank you Edward and stefan. I thought mutate was applied row-wise, but now I see it needs to return a vector.
